# What game is this screenshot from?

Tags: game-identification

Someone posted this screenshot. I asked what game it was but they didn't reply. It looks interesting. Anyone know?

[image]

Comment: Of interesting note, not only does the screenshot not return results on google images, but neither do the character icons at the bottom, or the game icons at the top. Could you perhaps provide any more information? Mainly, where it was posted, and in what context? It's only a shot, but there might be some extra information in there that one of our users can use as clues to hunt the title down.

Comment: Someone could ask one of the players http://silverwingwolf.tumblr.com but I'm not registering to Tumblr for that ...

Answer (score 11):

I found it. It's a mobile game called [Cutie Riot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rafo.riot&hl=en). I haven't played it (not only the character design...part dating sim? yuk!), but the HUD is the same (and that sword):

[image: Same HUD]

And the one girl (but reflected) from your screenshot is here:

[image: same girl]

Comment: I forgot I even asked what game this was. Sorry! But thank you to all that helped!

Comment: @HopeSellers Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it answered your question.